# Salary changes after unconditional offer

Tags: salary, job-offer

I was offered a job (conditionally) as a developer for an organisation at a pay rate lower than I am currently on. I decided to negotiate my rate showing evidence that I earn more at another organisation, and I was offered the top of the band in an email confirmation pending clearance of visas.

I was offered a letter showing what my rates were for purpose of visa which shows my negotiated rate. However, after clearing the visa requirement and losing my previous visa the new organisation is claiming I was offered a wrong rate (an error on their side they claim) and reckons I should be at a much lower rate.

My unconditional offer is now showing a lower rate. Do I even have options? Rejecting the job will mean being visaless.

Comment: Can you add a country tag for where you are going to work? It'll probably make a lot of difference regarding your options.

Comment: You say you have those offers in a letter and email, so that should be enough evidence to support your rate.

Comment: Fortunatelly you say they are only *claiming* that you should have lower rate, not actually denying to give you that rate. If they go back on their offer after you show evidence it would be unprofessional from their behalf. I suspect you would be better consulting a lawer. Is that letter you have that indicates your offer signed by them? That would be a good plus to your claim.

Comment: You need to find an "employment fraud and misrepresentation attorney". Call your state bar association for a referral. Also, note that your visa may be in jeopardy anyway even if you accept the new terms. Keep in mind that I am not a lawyer and I do not know what I am talking about, but I would assume that the INS probably wouldn't like the idea of a company applying for a visa with a very high salary, only to retroactively change the salary once the visa had been granted. Also, the circumstances sound so suspicious, I wouldn't be surprised if they routinely did the same to others.

Comment: Easy bait and switch. Could very well be that you're out of luck.

Comment: Not a lawyer, but if you can show that the company caused you to lose out significantly because of their 'mistake' a lawyer might be able to get you compensation. If you can show they did this deliberately, or had a pattern of it, you might get them convicted of fraud. Merely getting a lawyer involved might be enough to make them honour the offer.

Comment: Also don't forget you might be better off from a visa point of view if they terminate you from if you fail to accept their offer. In other words, never talk to them about 'accepting' or 'rejecting' the lower offer, always talk to them in terms of insistingon hold them to the original terms of the offer.

Answer (score 5):

I find it a little bit strange that a government agency would do something like this, but from all accounts it looks like a common bait and switch tactic. It works the following way:

1. Make the applicant an offer with a very nice desired rate
2. Complete a visa application listing that rate (Higher Salary = Higher chance to get a visa, usually)
3. Wait until it's too late for the applicant to go back.
4. Insert your desired terms into the offer in the knowledge that the applicant has no choice but to accept now.

I don't know if this is legal in your jurisdiction, but you probably need a consultation with an employment lawyer.

Generally speaking though, if you're in a country like the US with at-will employment, you may be out of luck here and your choice may be work for less or get thrown out. (Definitely do consult an employment lawyer though)

Comment: In Europe you can usually ask a labor union for advice too. They'll usually be savvy enough in labor law to give an educated answer, without any need to pay an attorney. (Though they might ask for a registration fee for the privilege.)